# If $\mathrm{rank}(A)>\mathrm{rank}(B)$ for matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $3$ then $\mathrm{rank}(A^2)\ge \mathrm{rank}(B^2)$

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $A, B \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ two matrices so that
>   $\mathrm{rank}(A) \gt \mathrm{rank}(B)$. Prove $\mathrm{rank}(A^2) \ge \mathrm{rank}(B^2)$

---

Suppose $B \ne 0_3$, otherwise it's obvious.

Of course, it $\mathrm{rank}(A)=3$ then $\mathrm{rank}(A^2)=3\ge \mathrm{rank}(B^2)$ so the only interesting case is when $rank(A)=2$. This case $rank(B)=1$.

I know $\mathrm{rank}(A^2) \le \mathrm{rank}(A) = 2$ and $\mathrm{rank}(B^2) \le \mathrm{rank}(B) = 1$. If $\mathrm{rank}(B^2) = 1$ I have to prove $\mathrm{rank}(A^2) \ge 1$.

**In other words I have to prove: $\mathrm{rank}(A) = 2$ implies $A^2 \ne 0_3$ and here I've got stuck.**

Any hint will be appreciated.

***I only need an elementary solution.***

Comment: The fact that these are matrices of dimension 3 is crucial (in dimension 4 or higher the result fails). Did you try to use this?

Comment: When is $rank(A^2)$ zero?

Comment: @Did The fact that he only looked at matrices of ranks $3$ and $2$ is using the fact that these matrices are of dimension $3$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Yeah, but one can go further using this.

Comment: Hint: For $A,B \in M_3(\mathbb{R})$, $\rank(AB) \geq \rank(A)+\rank(B)-3$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B) = 1$. Then $\operatorname{rank}(B^2) \leq \operatorname{rank}(B) = 1$. If $\operatorname{rank}(B^2) = 0$, the result is clear so assume $\operatorname{rank}(B^2) = 1$. Then we need to show that $\operatorname{rank}(A^2) \geq 1$. If $\operatorname{rank}(A^2) = 0$ then $A^2 = 0$ and so $A$ is nilpotent of nilpotency index two. But then we have

$$ \operatorname{Im}(A) \subseteq \ker(A) \implies \dim \ker A \geq 2, \dim \operatorname{Im}(A) = 2$$

which contradicts $\dim \ker A + \dim \operatorname{Im}(A) = 3$.

Comment: I need something elementary, can't use $\dim \ker A + \dim \operatorname{Im}(A) = 3$

Comment: Well, take a basis $w_1,w_2$ for $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ and complete it into a basis $w_1,w_2,w_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $Aw_1 = Aw_2 = 0$ and any vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as $w = a_1 w_1 + a_2 w_2 + a_3 w_3$. But then $Aw = a_3 Aw_3$ and so the image of $A$ is at most one dimensional contradicting $\operatorname{rank} A = 2$.

Comment: This problem is for kids who never heard of vectors, basis etc. It's easy to solve it using matrix diagonalization, but I can't use this either.

Comment: Well, what can you use? What is your definition of rank?